# Счётчик в столбце по ненулевым данным с учётом значений в ещё одном столбце

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, group-by

Есть посуточные показания датчиков. Необходимо задать счётчик ненулевых значений по датчикам и по количеству показаний, т.е. от первого ненулевого значения до нуля - 1; от следующего ненулевого значения до нуля -2; при этом для нового датчика счётчик должен начаться снова с 1.

Пример фрейма данных (англ. DataFrame):

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    d={
      'Дата':['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020'],
      'Датчик':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
      'Показания':[0,2,3,5,0,22,3,0,11,22]
    }
    df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Вид таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот этот пример](https://progi.pro/sozdanie-schetchika-kotoriy-uvelichivaetsya-esli-znachenie-v-predidushem-stolbce-otlichaetsya-no-sbrasivaetsya-pri-izmenenii-znacheniya-drugogo-stolbca-11185008), который ближе всего к моему вопросу, но я не до конца понимаю как его преобразовать, чтобы получить нужный результат.

Объединил оба примера в один и в результате получил нужный счётчик:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Дата':    ['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','06.02.2021','07.02.2021','08.02.2021','09.02.2021','10.02.2021','11.02.2021'],
  'Датчик': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3],
  'Показания':   [0,2,3,5,0,22,3,0,11,22,0,0,37,8,0,95] })

grp1=df[~df['Показания'].isin([0])] 
grp = grp1.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"]

first_idxs = grp.apply(lambda x: x.index[0])

df["счетчик"] = np.where(
    df["Показания"] != 0,
    df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"].apply(lambda x:  ((x.shift().eq(0) & x.ne(0))| (x.ne(0)&(x.index.isin(first_idxs))) ).cumsum()),
    0
)
df
          Дата  Датчик  Показания  счетчик
0   01.01.2020       1          0        0
1   02.01.2020       1          2        1
2   03.01.2020       1          3        1
3   04.01.2020       1          5        1
4   05.01.2020       1          0        0
5   01.01.2020       1         22        2
6   02.01.2020       2          3        1
7   03.01.2020       2          0        0
8   04.01.2020       2         11        2
9   05.01.2020       2         22        2
10  06.02.2021       3          0        0
11  07.02.2021       3          0        0
12  08.02.2021       3         37        1
13  09.02.2021       3          8        1
14  10.02.2021       3          0        0
15  11.02.2021       3         95        2
```

Может кто-нибудь более подробно объяснить что происходит в строчке

```
grp = grp1.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"]
```

При группировке по "Датчик" параметру "Показания" присваивается индекс первого встречного значения?

В этой строчке:

```
df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"].apply(lambda x:  ((x.shift().eq(0) & x.ne(0))| (x.ne(0)&(x.index.isin(first_idxs))) ).cumsum())
```

Функция lambda возвращает x если условие сработало и затем считается их количество? apply нужно чтобы применить функцию lambda к каждому датчику отдельно? интуитивно вроде понятно, но все же...

Comment: Ну вы намудрили. Я частично написал, но прямо чтобы точно как нужно пока не получилось.

Comment: Эт не я) Датчиков много и периоды у всех разные, + таких файлов много. надо иметь возможность сравнивать периоды показаний, вот для этого и нужен признак, по которому потом можно их группировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант ответа для измененных входных данных:

```
d = {
  'Дата':['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020'], 
  'Датчик':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
  'Показания':[0,2,3,5,0,22,0,0,11,22]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

решение:

```
df["счетчик"] = \
    df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"].apply(lambda x: (x.shift().eq(0) & x.ne(0)).cumsum())
```

результат:

```
In [110]: df
Out[110]:
         Дата  Датчик  Показания  счетчик
0  01.01.2020       1          0        0
1  02.01.2020       1          2        1
2  03.01.2020       1          3        1
3  04.01.2020       1          5        1
4  05.01.2020       1          0        1
5  01.01.2020       1         22        2
6  02.01.2020       2          0        0
7  03.01.2020       2          0        0
8  04.01.2020       2         11        1
9  05.01.2020       2         22        1
```

---

```
df["счетчик"] = np.where(
    df["Показания"] != 0,
    df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"].apply(lambda x:  (x.shift().eq(0) & x.ne(0)).cumsum()),
    0
)

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
          Дата  Датчик  Показания  счетчик
0   01.01.2020       1          0        0
1   02.01.2020       1          2        1
2   03.01.2020       1          3        1
3   04.01.2020       1          5        1
4   05.01.2020       1          0        0
5   01.01.2020       1         22        2
6   02.01.2020       2          3        0
7   03.01.2020       2          0        0
8   04.01.2020       2         11        1
9   05.01.2020       2         22        1
10  06.02.2021       3          0        0
11  07.02.2021       3          0        0
12  08.02.2021       3         37        1
13  09.02.2021       3          8        1
14  10.02.2021       3          0        0
15  11.02.2021       3         95        2
```

Comment: Это практически то, что нужно. Но в 4 строке стоит при нулевом показании 1, а должно быть ноль. Пытаюсь добавить условие np.where в лямда функцию, чтобы применять суммирование только если значение не равно нулю, но кажется это  так не работает...

Comment: @Alexandr, в своем первом ответе я уже показал как можно использовать `np.where()` для данной задачи )

Comment: добавил np.where, но не то

Comment: @Alexandr, надо быть внимательнее со скобочками - `df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"].apply(lambda x: (x.shift().eq(0) & x.ne(0)).cumsum())`. Вы применяете `.cumsum()` к результату `.apply()`, а надо применять к каждой группе внутри `.apply()`

Comment: попробую обнулить уже после счетчика...

Comment: в этом варианте, который вы предлагаете пишет ошибку, IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: можно как то в лямбда функцию добавить ещё одно условие по другому столбцу?

Comment: @Alexandr, у меня все работает на вашем воспроизводимом примере данных - смотрите дополненный ответ и результат...

Comment: 6 строка датчик 2, ненулевое значение - стоит счётчик ноль, а должен 1

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
grp = df.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"]

first_idxs = grp.apply(lambda x: x.index[0])

df["счетчик"] = np.where(
    df["Показания"] != 0,
    grp.apply(lambda x: (x.index.isin(first_idxs) | x.eq(0)).cumsum()),
    0
)
```

результат:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
         Дата  Датчик  Показания  счетчик
0  01.01.2020       1          0        0
1  02.01.2020       1          2        1
2  03.01.2020       1          3        1
3  04.01.2020       1          5        1
4  05.01.2020       1          0        0
5  01.01.2020       1         22        2
6  02.01.2020       2          3        1
7  03.01.2020       2          0        0
8  04.01.2020       2         11        2
9  05.01.2020       2         22        2
```

Comment: Спасибо! сейчас опробую

Comment: Попробовал. Код работает, но не для всех случаев. В частности, если задать первое показание второго датчика равным нулю, то счётчик сбивается. Сразу считает со 2-го...

Comment: чтобы получить правильные первые индексы ненулевых показаний датчика добавил grp1=df[~df['Показания'].isin([0])]
grp = grp1.groupby("Датчик")["Показания"] однако теперь затык с дальнейшей формулой

Comment: @Alexandr, можете привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: d={
  'Дата':['01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020','01.01.2020','02.01.2020','03.01.2020','04.01.2020','05.01.2020'],
  'Датчик':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
  'Показания':[0,2,3,5,0,22,0,0,11,22]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)